# Why can't I select the whole table?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm working on a way to export some tabular data from an HTML page to Excel using a program called DocRaptor. I'm using PHP to pass the data using their API which then converts the data to an Excel Spreadsheet.

I can't however seem to pass the whole table (including the opening `<table>` and closing `</table>` tags.

Say for example if I have the following table in HTML:

```
<table id="placement-table">
    <tr id="row">
    <td id="cell">Text1</td>
    </tr>
<tr id="row1">
    <td id="cell">Text2</td>
    </tr>
<tr id="row2">
    <td id="cell">Text3</td>
    </tr>
<tr id="row3">
    <td id="cell">Text4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Now for example if I use `console.log($('#placement-table').html());` I only get the following output:

```
<tbody><tr id="row">
    <td id="cell">Text1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row1">
    <td id="cell">Text2</td>
    </tr><tr id="row2">
    <td id="cell">Text3</td>
    </tr><tr id="row3">
    <td id="cell">Text4</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Why am I missing the actual opening and closing `<table></table>` tags? Is it because `.html()` only gives you the content inside of the given element? I realise I'm only logging the info to the Console but I'm just doing this so I can see what's being passed and hence why I noticed it was missing these tags.

Hope this makes sense, if not I can update the question!

Comment: relatively to jquery documentation , the .html() method gives you onlly the html content http://api.jquery.com/html/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Get selected element's outer HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419749/get-selected-elements-outer-html)

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.outerHTML = function() {
    return $(this).clone().wrap('<div></div>').parent().html();
  }
})(jQuery);

console.log($('#placement-table').outerHTML());    // <table>...</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `outerHTML`:

```
$('#placement-table')[0].outerHTML
```

or:

```
var table = document.getElementById('placement-table').outerHTML
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eQRL3/

Answer (score 0):

Correct; html() gets the content of the element you supply, and not the container itself. Simplest solution would be to add a wrapper div...

Answer (score 0):

Method `html` gets the innerHTML of the element. You should use something like `outerHTML`, which in jQuery can be done as follows:

```
var table = $("#placement-table").clone().wrap("<div />").parent().html();
console.log(table);
```